# Google App Engine : Get User Object from Webapp2 Cached Property (current_user)

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

What i am trying to achieve is getting the user object from the webapp2.cached property.
i have a method defined in my request handler which gives me the current user.

```
@webapp2.cached_property
  def current_user(self):
  user_dict = self.auth.get_user_by_session()
  return self.auth.store.user_model.get_by_id(user_dict['user_id'])
```

I want to get the User Object because it is a UserProperty() of one of my models which is as follows:

```
class CountryImage(db.Model):
  image = db.BlobProperty()
  user = db.UserProperty()
  country = db.ReferenceProperty(Country)
  approved = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)
```

Now when the upload form is posted, everything works fine except for the "user" which shows as "None" in the datastore.

The possible reason i found while i was playing with it in the interactive console was that
the method current_user passes a web cached property and not the actual user object.

For Example:

```
< webapp2.cached_property object at 0xb46aee8c >
```

Now my question is what would be the best possible way of retrieving the user object ? Thanks in advance for all your help.

Amyth

PS: EDIT:

following is the code where i am trying to store the image in the datastore:

```
NewImg = models.CountryImage()
NewImg.image = self.request.get('image')
NewImg.user = self.current_user
NewImg.country = models.Country.all().filter("url_name =", country).get()
continue_url = self.request.url
NewImg.put()
```

PS:

Just to add i have also tried using "users.get_current_user()" method which also returns "None"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your responses, however i have soved this already. In case you are using `User` model from `webapp2_extras` (which is an extension to User model from `appengine.api.users`) you can get the user as follows

```
from google.appengine.api import users
from webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models import User

user = users.User(User.get_by_auth_id(self.current_user.auth_ids[0]).name)
```

or

```
user = users.User(User.get_by_auth_id(self.current_user.auth_ids[0]).email)
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm curious, the country image, is that uploaded by users? or are you managing those as resources?

if not, you might be better to use a StringProperty on the user model, then reference a string path to a static image asset and save yourself the extra db lookups

Answer (score 0):

users.get_current_user() should be the way to go, but that requires the user to login first.
Are you trying to support anonymous users?

Comment: Nope, However we have custom session handling so the function returns None

Comment: In that case for the user object you cannot use the UserProperty, because that is only for the user objects returned by the Google Users API, which it looks like you're either not using, or you're disabling via your custom sessions.  You'll either need to switch and use the Google Users API, or use another way to store your user in your CountryImage model - ie as a string of the userid, or a ReferenceProperty to whatever user object you store in the datastore.

Comment: We're using the User model from webapp2_extras which i think is an extension to Google Users API as the new custom users are also being saved in the same table in datastore.

Comment: I don't know about webapp2_extras, but looking at it a bit closer, cached_property.current_user is method, so maybe it's just a syntax error NewImg.user = self.current_user()

Comment: using self.current_user() raises an error "User object is not callable"